# Using IF And Executing A Query If It's True

Tags: mysql

I have a query that i want it to be executed in a condition, for instance the api key .

Human :

If Api key is in the Api database, do the following query, say 'You Are Not Allowed' .

What i tried :

```
Select IF ( api.key = 'myapikey' , TrueQuery , 'You are not allowed') from api
```

My problem is in the query, i'm getting a lot of errors, the query contains " SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... LEFT JOIN " .

What's the way to accomplish it ?

Following example returns null :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT api.app FROM api WHERE api.app = 'Test' )
THEN (SELECT items.rom_id FROM items)
END
```

Comment: Edit TrueQuery to 'TrueQuery'

Comment: THEN (SELECT items.rom_id FROM items) must return only one result. If there're more than one result you will get an error

Comment: 'TrueQuery' is just a hint to the query, I've used Where clause to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, without using IF, but using EXISTS.

```
select *
from ( TrueQuery ) t
where exists(select 1 from api where api.key = 'myapikey')
```

Comment: Just switched to Where clause, it did the job .